# Database Offset & Limit without order by?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, query

To my understanding, in MySQL/Postgres database there is no guarantee for the order of values with a select statement without an order-by clause, thus one should be getting rows arbitrarily. If so, then why are there usually no duplicates when I perform such query?

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 0,5
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 5,5
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 10,5
```

Aren't these queries safe to use, considering that one only cares about not fetching duplicates and does not mind about the ordering? If so, how then?

Answer (score 6):

Your syntax won't work with PostgreSQL, but I can answer your question for PostgreSQL anyway:

Your query will often work as you intend because the three statements will often use the same execution plan. There is no guarantee for that though.

One possibility where even a sequential scan in PostgreSQL will return a different order is if there is already a sequential scan of the table in progress: Then PostgreSQL will start scanning where the other statement is currently scanning the table, i.e. somewhere in the middle, so that both scan can execute somewhat synchronized to reduce the I/O operations necessary.

Comment: *"Your query will often work as you intend because the three statements will often use the same execution plan. There is no guarantee for that though."* Indeed as standards defined SQL is to be orderless in tables, delivered tables/resultsets.. Pagination of anny kind requires a deterministic (fixed) sort.. The `ORDER BY` should atleast include one column in the `ORDER BY` which has a `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key.. to make to deterministic (fixed) on every run.. A non deterministic (random) sort can still give invalid results..

Answer (score 2):

If `DELETES` could be happening concurrently, `OFFSET` *will* lead to duplicates!  concurrent `INSERTs` or `UPDATEs` have other potential problems.

Furthermore, `OFFSET` involves scanning that many rows.  As you get farther and farther into the table, this gets slower and slower.  (It's not an issue for `LIMIT 10,5`, but it is an issue for `LIMIT 100000,5`.)

So, what to do?  "Remember where you left off" and get the next 5 rows.  *AND* use an `ORDER BY`, preferably the `PRIMARY KEY`.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) for discussion of the performance and bugs, plus how to deal with "left off" for a composite PK.

Note:  In MySQL (InnoDB), using the PK is better than using a `UNIQUE` key because you are doing `SELECT *` and want the data.  The data is clustered with the PK.